# How to get all the NFTs of particular smart contract

Tags: node.js, request, blockchain, ethereum, nft

I tried https://docs.opensea.io/reference opensea.io docs to fetch data. However, I think there are 2 APIs.

```
curl --request GET \
     --url https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/1/
```

This is for a single asset and it requires a token id as well. But I want data of all the NFTs of a particular smart contract address just by giving the smart contract address.

And this is for a single contract.

```
curl --request GET \
     --url https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset_contract/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `assets` endpoint ([docs](https://docs.opensea.io/reference#getting-assets)) has the `asset_contract_address` filter that allows you to filter by a contract address. Which will effectively allow you to paginate through all NFTs of the contract (that Opensea knows of).

Example:

```
curl 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?offset=0&limit=20&asset_contract_address=0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb'
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Is that possible to get all the NFTs of a particular asset_contract_address without pagination? Because I can see there is a max limit: 50 However, I want to perform computation on each NFT of any asset_contract_address.

Comment: @HaiderYaqoob Unfortunately the pagination is limited by the Opensea API, so it's not currently possible to bypass it.

Comment: @PetrHejda You ever had problem that they are not returning all assets. I/E on their page opnsea.io you see 88 and by api call you get only 7 example address:0x6f5174b6015238acf4ffdbece7c722a5911d104a

Comment: @programerAnel It seems that the [UI](https://opensea.io/kriscrypto87) (88 assets) takes the data from other sources as well than just the [API](https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?format=json&owner=0x6F5174b6015238ACF4FFdbeCe7c722A5911D104A) (7 assets). Unfortunately I don't know the other sources. It's possible that the UI includes some deleted or sold or in-order NFTs, while the API doesn't?

Comment: the url above no longer points to a valid response, however removing the pagination parameter `?offset=0&limit=20` does point the a response with the first 20 items in the contract (https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?asset_contract_address=0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb). Does anyone have an updated url with correct pagination parameters